# Multiple filters and drop down menus for plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a waterfall chart that I would like to have two drop down filter boxes for (one worked fine but it's the second one I am having trouble with). It seems to come up with the correct chart initially, but when I click a drop down box the chart either disappears or shows the wrong values for the given selection.

My data:

```
 my_data <- structure(list(Cohort = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("2003", "2006", "2009"), class = "factor"), ind = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Aspiration", "Gender", 
"Low_SES", "Parent_edu"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Aspiration", "Closest_uni_distance_g2", 
"Educ_occupation_quartile", "Family_structure", "Gender"), class = "factor"), 
    roll = c(0.0750803710978645, 0.076436441980399, 0.0925424424098545, 
    0.0950458976596428, 0.0917674134165381, -0.345423918218276, 
    -0.347660661701295, -0.356519150007063, -0.360758049199678, 
    -0.372940308381271, -0.0453779875920708, -0.0465416728725297, 
    -0.047252123130504, -0.0463144654922128, -0.127690827133109, 
    -0.0607795367471432, -0.0598934089046648, -0.0814516006011201, 
    -0.0836894858818226, -0.0840952435220562, 0.0874835324452846, 
    0.0912364919757644, 0.105777226141928, 0.106963827631275, 
    0.356379384253744, 0.36207727951625, 0.370840500815585, 0.384840489694092, 
    -0.0475543917831162, -0.0478582465019799, -0.0487284614746369, 
    -0.13308503060702, 0.0441449522093825, 0.0505563180773581, 
    0.0658006236043333, 0.0683279904326434, 0.07261902634577, 
    0.0778692418494206, 0.0872004492519247, 0.0850098679360723, 
    0.0838837730292262, 0.32446212681395, 0.328231007457026, 
    0.335365279883835, 0.332040073705212, 0.351959150036042, 
    0.0536891922354224, 0.0544669559094648, 0.0551853855166302, 
    0.0555352735715207, 0.133232816312245, 0.0519405537106114, 
    0.0591010371260817, 0.0794756801714813, 0.0793173156131281, 
    0.0777547869099181), base = c(0, 0.0750803710978645, 0.076436441980399, 
    0.0925424424098545, 0.0950458976596428, 0, -0.345423918218276, 
    -0.347660661701295, -0.356519150007063, -0.360758049199678, 
    0, -0.0453779875920708, -0.0465416728725297, -0.047252123130504, 
    -0.0463144654922128, 0, -0.0607795367471432, -0.0598934089046648, 
    -0.0814516006011201, -0.0836894858818226, 0, 0.0874835324452846, 
    0.0912364919757644, 0.105777226141928, 0, 0.356379384253744, 
    0.36207727951625, 0.370840500815585, 0, -0.0475543917831162, 
    -0.0478582465019799, -0.0487284614746369, 0, 0.0441449522093825, 
    0.0505563180773581, 0.0658006236043333, 0, 0.07261902634577, 
    0.0778692418494206, 0.0872004492519247, 0.0850098679360723, 
    0, 0.32446212681395, 0.328231007457026, 0.335365279883835, 
    0.332040073705212, 0, 0.0536891922354224, 0.0544669559094648, 
    0.0551853855166302, 0.0555352735715207, 0, 0.0519405537106114, 
    0.0591010371260817, 0.0794756801714813, 0.0793173156131281
    ), roll_minus_base = c(0.0750803710978645, 0.00135607088253455, 
    0.0161060004294555, 0.00250345524978828, -0.00327848424310467, 
    -0.345423918218276, -0.0022367434830185, -0.00885848830576863, 
    -0.00423889919261472, -0.0121822591815926, -0.0453779875920708, 
    -0.00116368528045896, -0.000710450257974227, 0.000937657638291178, 
    -0.0813763616408965, -0.0607795367471432, 0.000886127842478407, 
    -0.0215581916964553, -0.00223788528070247, -0.000405757640233637, 
    0.0874835324452846, 0.00375295953047973, 0.0145407341661632, 
    0.00118660148934696, 0.356379384253744, 0.00569789526250536, 
    0.00876322129933566, 0.0139999888785068, -0.0475543917831162, 
    -0.000303854718863766, -0.000870214972656977, -0.0843565691323827, 
    0.0441449522093825, 0.00641136586797556, 0.0152443055269752, 
    0.00252736682831006, 0.07261902634577, 0.00525021550365058, 
    0.00933120740250415, -0.00219058131585249, -0.00112609490684605, 
    0.32446212681395, 0.00376888064307568, 0.00713427242680886, 
    -0.00332520617862214, 0.0199190763308294, 0.0536891922354224, 
    0.000777763674042455, 0.000718429607165359, 0.000349888054890515, 
    0.0776975427407239, 0.0519405537106114, 0.00716048341547032, 
    0.0203746430453996, -0.000158364558353163, -0.00156252870321001
    ), Colour = c("rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", 
    "rgba(120, 162, 47, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code to create the chart:

```
p <- plot_ly(my_data, x = ~Category, y = ~base, type = 'bar',marker=list(color =  'rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)'),
             transforms = list(list( 
               type = 'filter',
               target = ~Cohort,
               operation = '=',
               value = unique(my_data$Cohort)[1]),
               list( 
                 type = 'filter',
                 target = ~ind,
                 operation = '=',
                 value = unique(my_data$ind)[1]))) %>% 
add_trace(y = ~roll_minus_base,  marker=list(color = ~Colour,
                                             line = list(color = ~Colour,width = 2))) %>% 
  layout(title = 'Decomposition',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "",
                      range = c(floor(min(my_data$roll)*10)/10, ceiling(max(my_data$roll)*10)/10)),
         barmode = 'stack',
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgba(245, 246, 249, 1)',
         plot_bgcolor = 'rgba(245, 246, 249, 1)',
         showlegend = FALSE,
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             type = 'dropdown',
             active = 0,
             buttons = apply(as.data.frame(unique(my_data$ind)), 1, 
                             function(x) list(method = 'restyle',args = list('transforms[2].value',x),label = x))),
           list(
             type = 'dropdown',
             active = 0,
             buttons = apply(as.data.frame(unique(my_data$Cohort)), 1, 
                             function(x) list(method = 'restyle',args = list('transforms[1].value',x),label = x)))
         ))
p
```

Comment: Could you explain what the expected output should be?

Comment: The output is a waterfall chart, but I want filter boxes so I can select the "ind" and "Cohort". The waterfall chart is just a stacked bar chart with two parts. The bottom part (which I called "base") is made invisible by making it the same colour as the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No major problems, the dropdown boxes are just referencing incorrect transformations.

- The $ind dropdown should reference 'transforms[1].value'
- The $cohort dropdown should reference 'transforms[0].value'

I'm pretty new to plotly but it appears the transformations have a 0:n list index rather than a 1:n list index like you may be used to in R.