Two dropdown menus to select Y and Y2 axes independently
I am trying to generate a plot which has independent dropdown menus for both Y and Y2 axes. I am able to implement a dropdown for either the Y1 or Y2 axis when the other is static. I have also generated a semi-solution making use of visible repeatedly and manually defining all combinations of Y-Y2, but this solution is messy and not exactly what I am looking for (see below). The ideal output is a 2 Y axis plot that has one dropdown menu for each axis where we can select any combination of a set list of variables. I'm assuming that my lack of understanding related to args is leaving me with no answers on this one.
The code that sort of works via visible and toggling Y and Y2 manually defined combinations of variables.
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(200), 
                  y = runif(200), 
                  z = runif(200), 
                  j = runif(200), 
                  k = rep(0.7, 200))

p <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~x) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~y,
            type = "scatter",
            visible = TRUE, 
            name = "Y1-Y") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~z, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            name = "Y1-Z") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ j, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            name = "Y1-J") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~k, 
            visible = TRUE,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-K") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~z, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-Z") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~j, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-J") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "X"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Y"),
    yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = "Y2"),
    updatemenus =
      list(list(y = 0.7,
                buttons = list(
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list(list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                     TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))),
                    label = "Y-K"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
                                                FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Y-Z"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
                                                FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "Y-J"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                                                TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "J-K"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                                                FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "J-Z"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
                                                TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Z-K")))
      )
  )

p

The below code is the closest I have gotten to 2 working buttons. This is obviously a flawed approach using visible. Is there a way to directly call Y2 into args, essentially "filtering" out Y1 variables?
p2 <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~x) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~y,
            type = "scatter",
            visible = TRUE, 
            name = "Y1-Y") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~z, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            name = "Y1-Z") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ j, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            name = "Y1-J") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~k, 
            visible = TRUE,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            name = "Y1-K") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~y, 
            visible = TRUE,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-Y") %>%
  # 2nd y axis
  add_trace(y = ~z, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-Z") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~j, 
            visible = FALSE,
            type = "scatter",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y2-J") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~k, 
            visible = TRUE,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            yaxis = "y2", 
            name = "Y1-K") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = "y2"),
         updatemenus =
           list(list(y = 0.7,
                     buttons = list(
                       list(
                         method = "restyle",
                         args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE,
                                                     FALSE, FALSE)),
                         label = "Y"),
                       list(
                         method = "restyle",
                         args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE,
                                                     FALSE, FALSE)),
                         label = "Z"),
                       list(
                         method = "restyle",
                         args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE,
                                                     TRUE, FALSE)),
                         label = "J"),
                       list(
                         method = "restyle",
                         args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE,
                                                     FALSE, TRUE)),
                         label = "K")
                     )
           ),
           # second list to add 2nd button on yaxis2
           # this is half working
           list(y = 0.7,
                x = 1.1,
                buttons = list(
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, 
                                                FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Y"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, 
                                                FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Z"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "J"),
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "K")
                )
           )
           )
  )

p2


On another note, is there anywhere that documents what exactly args is? I am having a hard time finding what can be put into args, making it extremely difficult to troubleshoot where things have not been documented on SO.

Why do you say this is flawed? You could do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718742/multiple-filters-and-drop-down-menus-for-plotly-in-r but it is not inherently different from what you are doing.

@M-- Well, it may work. But I am still struggling with how to call Y2 into args similar to how this example calls 'transforms[1].value'. I think that is the root of my issue.

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894919/how-to-set-the-values-of-args-and-args2-in-plotlys-buttons-in-updatemenus

The use of args has so many possibilities, it would be really difficult to document it properly. Have you looked at Plotly's R buttons' examples or Plotly's reference information on updatemenus? Using visible is one of the simplest approaches. I'm not a big user of crosstalk, but it may be useful for this project. In order to really help you, you'll have to be more specific I think, as to what you're looking for.
